# Why can't I start Eclipse and Minecraft at the same time?

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm running Java SE Development Kit Update 25 (64-bit).

It appears that I'm unable to run both Eclipse and Minecraft at the same time. This is really really weird, since I can easily start two instances of Minecraft (but not of Eclipse).

I'm guessing that the reason for this bug is that Eclipse is looking for other instances of itself when it starts (because it doesn't want to start more than once).

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: The great thing about Notch's Minecraft plugin for Eclipse is that it allows you to play Minecraft in Eclipse whilst waiting for your program to compile, also slowing down the compilation to give you time to find and tame your wolves.

Comment: Not sure if brilliant or evil :)

Answer (score 1):

You are running Java in a 64-bits environment, but are you allocating enough memory to it ?

The -Xms and -Xmx command line options could be what you need. They specify the initial and maximum size of the heap, respectively, and have low default values on some systems, depending on the way Java was installed.

I don't know what machine you run this on, and how much memory you can allocate, but if you use 64-bits architecture, I'd say `java -Xms1G -Xmx3G` is safe and will provide more space.